# ASP.NET5 Dependency Injection into a none controller class

Tags: c#, dependency-properties, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to get dependency injection working in a none controller class in ASP.NET 5.

I'm trying to inject an instance of **IHelloMessage** in **ResponseWriter**.

I have the following code in **startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IHelloMessage, HelloMessage>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            new ResponseWriter().Write(context);
        });
    });
}
```

I have the following code in **ResponseWriter.cs**:

```
public class ResponseWriter
{
    public IHelloMessage HelloMessage { get; set; }

    public ResponseWriter()
    {
    }
    public ResponseWriter(IHelloMessage helloMessage)
    {
        HelloMessage = helloMessage;
    }
    public void Write(HttpContext HttpContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(HelloMessage.Text);
    }
}
```

and here's the code for **HelloMessage**:

```
public interface IHelloMessage
{
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class HelloMessage : IHelloMessage
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public HelloMessage()
    {
        Text = "Hello world at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get the following error:
[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something silly - any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the HttpContext null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your parameter less constructor: `new ResponseWriter().Write(context);` so your HelloMessage is null.
If you want to use dependency injection you must use `IAppBuilder.ApplicationService.GetService` or `IAppBuilder.ApplicationService.GetRequiredService` methods

Your **statup.cs** can be:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IHelloMessage, HelloMessage>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            new ResponseWriter(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHelloMessage>()).Write(context);
        });
    });
}
```